# Can not find the mistake with displaying images in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

Hi I have this code from a previous web app I did. I just copied and pasted to a new one but images are not displaying in the new site. I even type code to show the path and it shows ok, to show the id and it shows ok and all properties from Products and they all show ok but images dont show. when F5 my app the site runs ok. but instead of images it shows only the tiny icon when img can not be loaded.Yet when using the inspector from the browser the src atribute has the correct path fro the image.
I can not find what is wrong
here is the code

This is Category Class

```
namespace Mysite.Models
{ 
    public class Category
    {
        //[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        //[Display(Name = "Product Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }

}
```

and this is Product Class

```
namespace Mysite.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        //[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Product Name")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name = "Product Description"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ImagePath { get; set; } // Here is the image path that I want to show           

        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the CategoryController that has a method Browse that INCLUDES Products

```
namespace Mysite.Controllers
{
    public class CategoriesController : Controller
    {
               private ProductContext db = new ProductContext();

              public ActionResult Browse(string categories)
        {
            var categoriaModel = db.Categories.Include("Products")
                .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == categories);
            return View(categoriaModel);/*(db.Categories.C)*/

        }
```

and this is the simplified view to test whether all I want to show in the browser , actually gets showed

```
@model Mysite.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
}

<h2>Browse</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model.Products) { 

<p>@item.ProductName , @item.ProductID , @item.ImagePath</p>

<img  src="@item.ImagePath"/>

}
```

but this is what it actually shows

```
Horizontal Faux Wood , 1 , Content/ProductImages/woodblind2.jpg /*small non-loaded picture icon here*/

Horizontal Real Wood , 2 , Content/ProductImages/woodblinds1.jpg /*small non-loaded picture icon here*/

Aluminium mini blinds , 10 , Content/ProductImages/aluminiumminiblind.jpg /*small non-loaded picture icon here*/
```

This same code I have it in another site working.
I double check the images folder, the route and all is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/" + item.ImagePath)"/>
```

Comment: This the one that worked . But can not understand why this and not the others even the other was OK( apparently)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: I am away from my pc  now but I guess this will work But how is this different from src"@item.ImagePath"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing th `/` before the `ImagePath` to specify the `root` and I would rather take the `string` variable out of another `""`. That's my approach anyway

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="~/@item.ImagePath" />`

Essentially the `~` symbol lets you reference files in relation to the root path.